# Trying to understand the wikipedia strategy pattern example using new Func<int, int, int>

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I was looking at this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern and I understand the concept of the strategy pattern, but could someone explain the C# example a bit.

I dont really get the how and why of the definition of 'Strategy' in the Context class, why is it `Func<T, T, T>` but then just two params are passed in eg 8,9 ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var context = new Context<int>();

    // Delegate
    var concreteStrategy1 = new Func<int, int, int>(PerformLogicalBitwiseOr);

    // Anonymous Delegate
    var concreteStrategy2 = new Func<int, int, int>(
        delegate(int op1, int op2)
        {
            return op1 & op2;
        });

    // Lambda Expressions
    var concreteStrategy3 = new Func<int, int, int>((op1, op2) => op1 >> op2);
    var concreteStrategy4 = new Func<int, int, int>((op1, op2) => op1 << op2);

    context.Strategy = concreteStrategy1;
    var result1 = context.Execute(8, 9);

    context.Strategy = concreteStrategy2;
    var result2 = context.Execute(8, 9);

    context.Strategy = concreteStrategy3;
    var result3 = context.Execute(8, 1);

    context.Strategy = concreteStrategy4;
    var result4 = context.Execute(8, 1);

}

static int PerformLogicalBitwiseOr(int op1, int op2)
{
    return op1 | op2;
}

class Context<T>
{
    public Func<T, T, T> Strategy { get; set; }

    public T Execute(T operand1, T operand2)
    {
        return this.Strategy != null
            ? this.Strategy(operand1, operand2)
            : default(T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A `Func<T1,T2,TResult>` is a delegate in the form of:

```
TResult function(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

so, the Func has 2 argument types, and 1 return type. Therefore when consuming the func, you'll type

```
 (arg1, arg2) => return new TResult();
```

Comment: Do you mean: T function(T1 arg1, T2 arg2) ?

Comment: You can name `T` everything you want, so here `TResult` for better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`Func<int, int, int>` is a func that take two int arguments and returns an int - the last type in a Func definition is the return type.

Answer (score 1):

A `Func<T, T1, T2>` is a delegate. A delegate is a type which represents a single function. In C# you can use functions like this instead of declaring a specific interface. If you wanted, you could use an interface which would look something like this:

```
interface IStrategy
{
     T Compute<T1, T2>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Func<T, T1, T2>` is a delegate, and [any delegate can be viewed as an anonymous interface](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/28/DelegatesAreAnonymousInterfaces.aspx).